# What exactly does washing mean in Islam?

Tags: islamic-basis, taharah

In Islam, in order to purify an impure object or area, it can be washed. Does this mean diluting the impurity until you cannot taste it, smell it, or see it's color? Or does it mean using water to remove it and transfer it somewhere else?

I see both answers in many sites and I am aware that for some impurities (like dog saliva/blood), you need to wash it seven times and one of them should be with dust or sand. I'm just confused on what exactly washing means in Islam because it is causing me many doubts about purifying myself.

Thank you and praise be to Allah.

Comment: "Does this mean diluting the impurity until you cannot taste it, smell it, or see it's color? Or does it mean using water to remove it and transfer it somewhere else?" is there a difference?

Comment: Can you please clarify which one is right?